# Supersymmetry in Quantum Field Theory

Tags: supersymmetry, resource-recommendations

I have an idea of supersymmetry in quantum mechanics, can you suggest a book on "supersymmetry in quantum field theory", which has sufficient mathematical rigour like "Peskin and Schroeder"

Comment: Peskin and Schroeder is mathematically quite sloppy, far from sufficient rogor.

Comment: @Arnold Neumair : Well I know that Peskin and Schroeder is not so mathematically rigorous, but I needed a book of that sort of mathematical rigour.

Comment: FYI: Found [these SUSY lectures](http://people.sissa.it/~bertmat/teaching.htm) by Matteo Bertolini online, which also links to other online SUSY lectures (although mathematical rigor seems not to be the primary objective here).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Book by Wess & Bagger is in my opinion the best book on Supersymmetry. It is written in a style that is meant for application in QFT, meaning, it is not too abstract and has alot of exercises.

Most papers I have read are written using the notation of Wess & Bagger. This might be due to the fact that Wess (together with Zumino) is one of the first people to actually use SUSY in a 4D QFT context.

[http://www.amazon.com/Supersymmetry-Supergravity-Julius-Wess/dp/0691025304](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691025304)

Answer (score 4):

A review paper:

[Stephen P. Martin - A Supersymmetry Primer](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9709356)

A nice overview of SUSY (still relevant):

[Keith R. Dienes, Christopher Kolda - Twenty Open Questions in Supersymmetric Particle Physics](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9712322)

A book aimed at accessibility:

[Labelle - Supersymmetry DeMYSTiFied](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071636412)