# Reference request for supersymmetry

Tags: resource-recommendations, supersymmetry

I have a good background in linear algebra, Topology and Differential geometry. I would like to understand the concept of supersymmetry in theoretical physics, and hopefully read Witten's landmark paper *Supersymmetry and Morse theory* sometime later. Please suggest suitable references. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30353/2451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to learn supersymmetry in my opinion is to watch lectures on it. Fernando Quevedo has a terrific lecture series available online [here](http://www.sms.cam.ac.uk/collection/659537). He also has accompanied [lecture notes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1491) with homework exercise which are crucial to do in order to get a good grasp of the material.

There are also many other free lecture notes on line which you can find by googling supersymmetry lecture notes.

Comment: http://www.sns.ias.edu/pitp2/index2010_final.html I found this resource recently. Seems to be good.

Comment: @SandeepThilakan, nice post. From my brief look at the topics, I wouldn't suggest it as an introduction into Supersymmetry, but definitely as an extension.