# Learning about super-symmetric quantum mechanics and integrable systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, supersymmetry, education, integrable-systems

I'm an undergraduate interested in theory. I recently asked one of my professors, a physicist in the particle theory group at my school, if he'd be willing to take on an undergraduate for a senior project. He told me to check back in at the end of the quarter, and that he might have a project related to super-symmetric quantum mechanics and integrable systems that may be feasible for me to try out then.

In the meantime, I want to familiarize myself as much as possible with the relevant math and physics so that I can impress him when I ask again. Do any of you have any books/online sources that you recommend I take a look at?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26912 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30353 and links therein.

Comment: see also the answer at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/16267/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regarding **supersymmetric quantum mechanics**:

By all means you should read and absorb the source of all supersymmetric quantum mechanics, which is still probably the deepest article on this topic, namely the original

- Edward Witten *[Supersymmetry and Morse theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/supersymmetric+quantum+mechanics#Witten82)*

This is one fourth of the [work that won Witten the Fields medal](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Edward+Witten#FieldMedalWork) in 1990.

When I learned this stuff back then, I was very much enchanted by the perspective of spectral geometry (i.e. Connes' spectral triples) that is highlighted in the survey

- Jürg Fröhlich, Oiver Grandjean, Andreas Recknagel, *[Supersymmetric quantum theory, non-commutative geometry, and gravitation](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/supersymmetric+quantum+mechanics#FGR97)*

I'd say if you read that in parallel with Witten, you'll end up with a rather profound understanding of what the deep aspects here are. Because, as you will notice, the topic of susy QM has the tendency to make many people write many rather shallow articles. Stay clear of them and focus on the substantial stuff here.

Speaking of substance, of course the full conceptual impact of supersymmetric QM rests in its [relation to index theory and K-theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/supersymmetric+quantum+mechanics#RelationToIndexTheory). You may not need that for your physics project (depends), but for your own education I'd suggest to at least look at the surveys and get the basic idea. This is tremendous stuff.

Finally a fun fact to know -- in particular when somebody quizzes you on applications or is sceptical about the value of supersymmetry -- is that every fermion particle is described by relativistic supersymmetric quantum mechanics *on its worldline*. See [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/supersymmetric+quantum+mechanics#RelationToSpinningParticles). This is in itself a somewhat trivial fact really, but drastically underappreciated. It is of course directly related to the way that Witten initially bumped into susy QM in the first place, namely by considering the [point-particle limit of superstrings](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/supersymmetric+quantum+mechanics#RelationToSuperstrings).

Answer (score 0):

For an elementary introduction to supersymmetric quantum mechanics see

*Supersymmetry and Quantum Mechanics* by Cooper et al. available at

http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9405029

Comment: Link-only answer are bad answers by definition.